# Access .env file from Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to access variables from .env file from Content Script?
I am building a Chrome Extension and I have javascript Content Script file from which I listen to events on the browser page.
I would like to make an API call, so I need to access my API key, which is stored in .env file. When i try to call variables as `const key = proccess.env.API_KEY` i get an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

I tried `require('dotenv').config();` to help me with that problem, but since this is a normal js file and not Node.js, i get an erorr: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

So is there a way to load .env variables in normal JavaScript? Or should I use different approach?

Comment: Browsers don't run `node` so there's no `process` and no `env`. You will have to include the key in your js files or switch to using tokens granted for the current user after they authenticate on your server.